# What's the different between Jersey @Consumes and @Produces

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

What's the different between Jersey `@Consumes` and `@Produces`? I'm confused within Jersey Restful service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Consumes` specifies what MIME type a resource accepts from the client. `@Produces`, however, specifies what MIME type a resources *gives* to the client. For example, a resource might accept `application/json` (`@Consumes`) and return `text/plain` (`@Produces`).

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/6nisfjmko/index.html

Comment: flawless answer!